# Como somar a diagonal de uma matriz em C?

Tags: c, matriz, array

Me ajudem no seguinte exercício:

Faça um programa que defina uma matriz de inteiros de tamanho 5x5. Em seguida,
inicialize essa matriz com números aleatórios entre 5 e 9. Finalmente, seu programa deve calcular a soma dos elementos da diagonal dessa matriz. O programa deve imprimir a matriz gerada e a soma de sua diagonal. Segue um exemplo de saída.
Matriz gerada:

```
5 6 7 8 9
9 5 6 7 8
8 9 5 6 7
7 8 9 5 6
6 7 8 9 5
```

A soma da diagonal da matriz é: 25.

O código que fiz, não faz a soma corretamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

    int matriz[5][5];
    int i, x, j, p;
    int soma=0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Matriz gerada: ");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("\n");
            for(j=0; j<5; j++){
                x=5+(rand()%5);
                printf("%3d", x);
                matriz[i][j];
                if(i==j){
                    for(p=0; p<5; p++){
                        soma+=matriz[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Soma da diagonal principal: %d", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O problema é que você não atualiza o valor da célula da matriz quando sorteia o número. Ao invés de fazer `matriz[i][j];`, faça `matriz[i][j] = x;` na terceira linha dentro do `for` mais interno. Provavelmente é um erro de digitação. :)

Comment: CORREÇÃO: Eu retirei o for da soma, tava somando varias vezes. muito obrigado Luiz Vieira!

Comment: O terceiro `for` com a variável `p` não faz sentido. Como você disse, o terceiro `for` faz a soma contar cada célula no meio cinco vezes.

Answer (score 4):

Seu código tinha basicamente dois problemas. Como o @Luiz Vieira [mencionou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126884/#comment264528_126884), você não estava guardando o valor de `x` na matriz. Além disso, como você mesmo notou, tinha um loop desnecessário fazendo a soma.

Para facilitar a leitura, foram removidas todas as variáveis redundantes e dada uma leve enxugada no código, já resolvendo os dois problemas mencionados:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
    int matriz[5][5];
    int i, j;
    int soma=0;

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    printf( "Matriz:\n" );
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ){
            matriz[i][j] = 5 + rand() % 5;
            printf( "%3d", matriz[i][j] );
            if( i==j ){
                soma += matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "Soma da diagonal principal: %d", soma );
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7dCxAS)**.

Agora, imaginando que você tivesse que somar a diagonal de uma matriz pré-existente, veja como ficaria o loop da soma, se fosse independente do resto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int matriz[5][5];
    int i, j;
    int soma = 0;

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    /* gerando a matriz */
    printf( "Matriz:\n" );
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
            matriz[i][j] = 5 + rand() % 5;
            printf( "%3d", matriz[i][j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    /* fazendo a soma */
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        soma += matriz[i][i];
    }
    printf("Soma da diagonal principal: %d", soma);

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/1KLQkP)**.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz de um jeito que nao precisa nem de if, no C, sou novo na programação mas se isso for ajudar em alguma coisa, tá aqui:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
     main()
    {
         int D[5][5], i=0, j=0, soma1=0,soma2=0 ,x=5;
          printf("--------------------------\ninforme os valores da matriz\n____________________________\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){   
    x--;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        printf("%d - %d = ",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%d",&D[i][j]);
    }
    soma1=soma1+D[i][i];
    soma2=soma2+D[i][x];
}
printf("\n-----------\nsoma diagonal 1:\t%d",soma1);
printf("\n-----------\nsoma diagonal 2:\t%d",soma2);
```

}